# JS (ES6): Merge arrays based on id and concatenating sub arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, ecmascript-6, array-merge

I have two arrays, which look like this:

```
const persons = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Peter',
    job: 'Programmer'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jeff',
    job: 'Architect'
  },
];

const salaries = [
  {
    id: 1,
    salary: 3000,
    departments: ['A', 'B'] 
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    salary: 4000,
    departments: ['A', 'C']
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    salary: 4000,
    departments: ['C', 'D']
  }
];
```

Now I need to somehow merge this arrays to one, so that every id only exists once. Same keys should be replaced, except it is an array, then I want them to add/concat. So the desired result should look something like this:

```
const result = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Peter',
    job: 'Programmer',
    salary: 4000,
    departments: ['A', 'B', 'C'] 
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jeff',
    job: 'Architect',
    salary: 4000,
    departments: ['C', 'D']
  }
];
```

I have already tried:

```
// double id's, arrays get replaced
Object.assign({}, persons, salaries)

// loadsh: double id's, arrays get concatenated
_.mergeWith(persons, salaries, (objValue, srcValue) => {
    if (_.isArray(objValue)) {
        return objValue.concat(srcValue);
    }
});

// gives me a map but replaces arrays
new Map(salaries.map(x => [x.id, x])
```

Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: I'll give you a hint sort both the arrays with respect to id and then try to compare em

Comment: what's the logic to understand which of the salary should be taken? the latest? the highest salary?

Comment: @MiguelAngel the latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the arrays, than combine all items with the same `id` using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

to combine objects with the same `id`, get the object from the Map. Iterate the new [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Check if existing value is an array, if not assign the value. If it is an array, combine the arrays, and make the items unique using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with array [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

To convert the Map back to an array, you can spread the [`Map.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) iterator.

```js
const persons = [{"id":1,"name":"Peter","job":"Programmer"},{"id":2,"name":"Jeff","job":"Architect"}];
const salaries = [{"id":1,"salary":3000,"departments":["A","B"]},{"id":1,"salary":4000,"departments":["A","C"]},{"id":2,"salary":4000,"departments":["C","D"]}];

const result = [...persons.concat(salaries)
  .reduce((r, o) => {
    r.has(o.id) || r.set(o.id, {});
    
    const item = r.get(o.id);
    
    Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) =>
      item[k] = Array.isArray(item[k]) ? 
        [...new Set([...item[k], ...v])] : v
    );
    
    return r;
  }, new Map()).values()];
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [`Spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to achieve required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const persons = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Peter',
    job: 'Programmer'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jeff',
    job: 'Architect'
  }],
  salaries = [{
    id: 1,
    salary: 3000,
    departments: ['A', 'B']
  }, {
    id: 1,
    salary: 4000,
    departments: ['A', 'C']
  }, {
    id: 2,
    salary: 4000,
    departments: ['C', 'D']
  }];


let output = persons.map(obj => {
  let filter = salaries.filter(v => v.id == obj.id);
  if (filter) {
    let departments = filter.reduce((r, v) => [...v.departments, ...r], []);
    Object.assign(obj, {
      salary: filter[filter.length - 1].salary,
      departments: departments.filter((item, pos) => departments.indexOf(item) == pos).sort()
    });
  }
  return obj;
});

console.log(output)
```

Comment: would you be able to help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60222532/combine-2-lists-into-one-using-arrow-function?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Map` and iterate all properties and check the type for adding unique values to the arrays.

```js
var persons = [{ id: 1, name: 'Peter', job: 'Programmer' }, { id: 2, name: 'Jeff', job: 'Architect' }],
    salaries = [{ id: 1, salary: 3000, departments: ['A', 'B'] }, { id: 1, salary: 4000, departments: ['A', 'C'] }, { id: 2, salary: 4000, departments: ['C', 'D'] }],
    result = Array.from(
        salaries
            .reduce(
                (m, o) => {
                    var t = m.get(o.id) || {};
                    Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
                        if (Array.isArray(o[k])) {
                            t[k] = t[k] || [];
                            o[k].forEach(v => t[k].includes(v) || t[k].push(v));
                        } else if (t[k] !== o[k]) {
                            t[k] = o[k];
                        }
                    });
                    return m;
                },
                persons.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.id, Object.assign({}, o)), new Map)
            )
            .values()
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```