# Combine 2 lists into one using map & arrow function

Tags: ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have 2 lists and I want to combine them so that I can populate them into a list. I know this can be done using nested for loops but, I'm trying to avoid for loops because of the amount of data I'll have to loop on. I would like to achieve this using the arrow functions or anything else.

**List One:**

```
let fields = [
    {
        field: "Name",
        fieldType: "Text"
    },
    {
        field: "Active__c",
        fieldType: "Boolean"
    },
    {
        field: "Contact",
        fieldType: "Relationship"
    }
];
```

**List Two:**

```
let rows = [
    {
        contact: {
            Name: "Joe",
            Active__c: true,
            Contact: "SomeContact"
        }
    },
    {
        contact: {
            Name: "Rachel",
            Active__c: true
        }
    },
    {
        contact: {
            Name: "Ross",
            Active__c: true
        }
    },
    {
        contact: {
            Name: "Monica",
            Active__c: true
        }
    }
];
```

**Current code:**

```
let output = rows.map(row => ({
    id: row.Id,
    data: {
        value: fields.map(field => (row.contact[field.field])),
        field: fields.map(field => field.field)
    }
}));
```

**The output of this code:**

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "value": [
                "Joe",
                true,
                "SomeContact"
            ],
            "field": [
                "Name",
                "Active__c",
                "Contact"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "value": [
                "Rachel",
                true,
                null
            ],
            "field": [
                "Name",
                "Active__c",
                "Contact"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "value": [
                "Ross",
                true,
                null
            ],
            "field": [
                "Name",
                "Active__c",
                "Contact"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "value": [
                "Monica",
                true,
                null
            ],
            "field": [
                "Name",
                "Active__c",
                "Contact"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

**Desired output:**

```
[
    data : [
        [
            {
                field : "Name",
                type: "Text",
                value : "Joe"
            },
            {
                field : "Active__c",
                type: "Boolean",
                value : true
            },
            {
                field : "Contact",
                type: "Relationship",
                value : "SomeContact"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                field : "Name",
                type: "Text",
                value : "Rachel"
            },
            {
                field : "Active__c",
                type: "Boolean",
                value : false
            },
            {
                field : "Contact",
                type: "Relationship",
                value : "SomeContact Two"
            }
        ],
        [
            ...
        ],
        [
            ...
        ]
    ]
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` property is unique and it has to be defined inline creating an object (*not an array as you have in your desired output*). You have to map `fields` array to each element of `rows` and then fill each `field` data with the `row` data if they exist. Also, I can't see an `Id` field on any row object inside `rows` array. This code sets `null` if a `field` does not exists:

```js
let output = {
  data: rows.map(({ contact }) => 
    fields.map(({ field, fieldType: type }) => ({
      field,
      type,
      value: field in contact ? contact[field] : null // Set null if contact has no field
    }))
  )
}
```

Run this code snippet to see the results:

```js
let fields = [
  {
    field: "Name",
    fieldType: "Text"
  },
  {
    field: "Active__c",
    fieldType: "Boolean"
  },
  {
    field: "Contact",
    fieldType: "Relationship"
  }
];

let rows = [
  {
    contact: {
      Name: "Joe",
      Active__c: true,
      Contact: "SomeContact"
    }
  },
  {
    contact: {
      Name: "Rachel",
      Active__c: true
    }
  },
  {
    contact: {
      Name: "Ross",
      Active__c: true
    }
  },
  {
    contact: {
      Name: "Monica",
      Active__c: true
    }
  }
];

let output = {
  data: rows.map(({ contact }) => 
    fields.map(({ field, fieldType: type }) => ({
      field,
      type,
      value: field in contact ? contact[field] : null
    }))
  )
}

document.getElementById('output').appendChild(
  document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2))
);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. It's not the loops you should worry about, but algorithm's complexity. As I see, you have optional fields in `rows`, and you didn't ask for `null` values in desired output. So, I'd propose a solution different from the one of Christos Lytras.
   Iterating over `fields` in each row iteration will give you `O(N^M)` complexity. Where `N` - is `rows.length`, and `M` is `fields.length`. This is possibly a bad idea. The following code will give you linear complexity `O(N+M)`. Where `M` is still `fields.length` and `N` is a sum of numbers of fields in each row of `rows`, it sounds even scarier than `O(N^M)` but, if you have optional fields it will save you a fortune - look for `called X times` in snippet output.

   ```js
   // prepare dictionary, later on fields_dict[field] will have O(1) complexity
   const fields_dict = fields.reduce((acc, {field, fieldType}) => {
       acc[field] = fieldType
       return acc
   }, {})

   let output2 = {
       data: rows.map(({ contact }) =>
           Object.keys(contact).map(field => ({ // iterate only over existing fields
               field,
               type: fields_dict[field],
               value: contact[field],
           }))
       )
   }
   ```
2. And by the way

   > I know this can be done using nested for loops but, I'm trying to avoid for loops because of the amount of data I'll have to loop on function

   ...even in modern browsers loops are superior in performance to `map()`, `reduce()` and Co., not the other way around.

   Look at the timings in the snippet. At least in my environment `for` version is twice as fast as `map` version (on the first run). Of cause, at that moment code is in no way **hot** by the standards of JIT-compiler, so code haven't been optimized by the browser. After JIT-compilation difference in performance become negligible (press `Run code snippet` for a couple of times to see). Still, loops **are faster**, at least on the first run.

   But if you won't test performance of you code, then don't bother microoptimizing it. Better think of algorithm complexity. And, yes, use functional style - it's both easier to write and to read.

   ```js
   let fields = [
    { field: "Name"     , fieldType: "Text" },
    { field: "Active__c", fieldType: "Boolean" },
    { field: "Contact"  , fieldType: "Relationship" },

    { field: "extra1"   , fieldType: "something" },
    { field: "extra2"   , fieldType: "something" },
    { field: "extra3"   , fieldType: "something" },
    { field: "extra4"   , fieldType: "something" },
   ];

   let rows = [
    { contact: { Name: "Joe"   , Active__c: true, Contact: "SomeContact" } },
    { contact: { Name: "Rachel", Active__c: true } },
    { contact: { Name: "Ross"  , Active__c: true } },
    { contact: { Name: "Monica", Active__c: true } },

    { contact: { Name: "Monica", Active__c: true } },
    { contact: { Name: "Monica", Active__c: true } },
    { contact: { Name: "Monica", Active__c: true } },
    { contact: { Name: "Monica", Active__c: true } },
    { contact: { Name: "Monica", Active__c: true } },
    { contact: { Name: "Monica", Active__c: true } },
   ];

   let i

   i = 0
   console.time("Christos Lytras version")
   let output1 = {
    data: rows.map(({ contact }) => 
     fields.map(({ field, fieldType: type }) => (i++,{
      field,
      type,
      value: field in contact ? contact[field] : null
     }))
    )
   }
   console.timeEnd("Christos Lytras version")
   console.log(`called ${i} times`)

   i = 0
   let j = 0
   console.time("functional version")
   const fields_dict = fields.reduce((acc, {field, fieldType}) => { i++, acc[field] = fieldType; return acc }, {})
   let output2 = {
    data: rows.map(({ contact }) => Object.keys(contact).map(field => (j++,{
     field,
     type: fields_dict[field],
     value: contact[field],
    })))
   }
   console.timeEnd("functional version")
   console.log(`called ${i+j} times`)

   i = 0
   console.time("loop version")
   const fields_dict2 = {}
   for(const {field, fieldType} of fields) { i++; fields_dict2[field] = fieldType }
   const output3 = { data: new Array(rows.length) }
   j = 0
   for(let r = 0 ; r !== rows.length ; ++r ) {
    const contact = rows[r].contact
    const contact_another_format = output3.data[r] = []
    for(const field in contact) {
     j++
     contact_another_format.push({
      field,
      type: fields_dict2[field],
      value: contact[field],
     })
    }
   }
   console.timeEnd("loop version")
   console.log(`called ${i+j} times`)

   // console.log(JSON.stringify(output1, undefined, 2))
   // console.log(JSON.stringify(output2, undefined, 2))
   console.log(JSON.stringify(output3, undefined, 2))

   console.log("results are equal:", JSON.stringify(output2) === JSON.stringify(output3)) // intentionally not equal to output1
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, after I posted this question I did run the performance test and for loop did perform well (by a bit) for the amount of data I have but, I still wanted to how it can be done by using a map :)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed a bit of code and removed a conditional check if field exists in contact as javascript will by default return undefined

```
let output = {
  data: rows.map(({ contact }) => 
    fields.map(({ field, fieldType: type }) => ({
      field,
      type,
      value: contact[field] // It wills et undefined if field key not present in contact
    }))
  )
}
```